# Convert hex string to 32 Bit binary in PHP

Tags: php, binary, hex

I need to convert a 64 sign hex to a 32 Bit binary. How to do this in PHP ? Is 'pack' the right function ?

Example hex to convert: D115E7B757EDE630CD0AA11142DC32661AB38829CA52A6422AB782862F268622

Comment: `pack` is mostly the right function for those tasks, but in your case, there is `hex2bin` function. Have you tried it? EDIT: It does not exist in PHP5. Look up `base_convert` or `pack`. Sorry about that.

Comment: Do you really mean 32 Bit binary? 32 bits for each hex pair? for each hex character? for each block of 4 or of 8 hex characters?

Comment: go and check this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i'm undestand your question, see [unpack](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unpack.php):

```
$hexadecimal = 'D115E7B757EDE630CD0AA11142DC32661AB38829CA52A6422AB782862F268622';
var_dump(unpack('L*', $hexadecimal));
```

Where flag L is unsigned long (always 32 bit, machine byte order)